# How to reference multiple files within a jQuery plugin directory?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm working on a custom ad plugin for jQuery that uses multiple files.

Example being if the plugin is located at:

```
root/jquery/myplugin/jquery.myplugin.js
```

I would need to reference another files like:

```
root/jquery/myplugin/units/ads.json
root/jquery/myplugin/units/default-728x90.png
```

The json file would contain necessary information for the ads such as the template name, class name, template image, etc.

Is there a method to determine the directory of "root/jquery/myplugin/"? I could use a parameter to set the default location but it'd prefer to simplify the code.

Thanks for your advice. :)

Comment: There's such a thing as relative URL's

Comment: You can do that if it's the actual directory. But how can you get a relative URL in the actual script? The file my be root/page.html but the javascript file is in another location.

Comment: That's true I suppose. You could get the window.location, search for your script tag in the DOM, and find the source for that, and then figure out where you're at.

Comment: Was thinking of that idea as well. Was just hoping for a more robust solution. I've seen plugins like plupload reference multiple files based on the relative URL of the plugin. Not sure how they did it.

Comment: On a project I'm using now in PHP I write the JS file via a php script, allowing me to write in the application base directory dynamically, which means I can set it from the PHP config settings for my application. Extra sweet :) You could simply make your main script /script/main.js.php and set up an htaccess to serve that when somebody requests /script.main.js ... Just a thought.